# Segmentation fault when printing an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

When I try to pass my array to a function and print it's values, I get a `Segmentation fault` error. I am very new to C programming and was trying to figure this out for a long time. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please show me the solution with sample code if possible.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void myfun(int **arr);

int main(int args, char** argv)
{            
    int arr[3][3] = {{3, 8, 6}, {2, 3, 2}, {4, 1, 2}};  
    myfun((int **) arr[3]);  
    return 0;
}

void myfun(int **arr) 
{
   int i;   
   for(i=0; i<3; i++) 
   {      
      printf("arr[1][i]:%d\n",arr[1][i]);//Gives Segmentation fault
   }   
}
```

Comment: I've seen this before.   Recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your function parameter issues, you also have your array indexes swapped in the function. i.e.:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void myfun (int arr[][3]);

int main (void)
{            
    int arr[3][3] = {{3, 8, 6}, {2, 3, 2}, {4, 1, 2}};  
    myfun (arr); 

    return 0;
}

void myfun (int arr[][3]) 
{
    int i;   

    for(i=0; i<3; i++) 
    {      
        printf (" arr[i][1]:%d\n", arr[i][1]); // OK now
    }   
} //result  show 8, 3, 1
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/arr_pass_2d
 arr[i][1]:8
 arr[i][1]:3
 arr[i][1]:1
```

**Note:** `arr[i][1]` not `arr[1][i]`

Additionally, if you update your `printf` call in the function, you can include the row value as well. e.g.:

```
    printf (" arr[%d][1]:%d\n", i, arr[i][1]);
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/arr_pass_2d
 arr[0][1]:8
 arr[1][1]:3
 arr[2][1]:1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a two dimensional array as a double pointer.  For a multidimentional array, the function needs to know all dimensions except the last one.

So define `myfunc` like this:

```
void myfun(int arr[3][3]);
```

And call it like this:

```
myfun(arr);
```

Comment: "the function needs to know all dimensions except the last one." -- almost -- "the function needs to know the last one." `void myfun(int arr[][3]);` is fine.

Comment: @dbush Thank you for showing with an example. When I make the changes as you suggested, I get the following two errors: `1) error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)[3]' to 'int'` 
`2) error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void myfun(int)'`